# How to fetch data from api by angular 5

Tags: php, angular

I have data service that fetch data from my api:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

showProducts(){
return this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/products');
}

}
```

and my component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
//import { Products } from '../products';

@Component({
selector: 'app-products',
templateUrl: './products.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./products.component.css']
})
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {
products;

constructor(private data:DataService) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.showProducts();
}
showProducts() {
this.data.showProducts()
  .subscribe(res => this.products = res);
}

}
```

and my html compopnent:

```
<div>
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <th>Product</th>
  <th>Code</th>
  <th>Price</th>
  <th>Action</th>
</tr>
<tr *ngFor="let product of products">
    {{product.product_name}}
</tr>
</table>


</div>
```

the problem here that i got this error when i run my code in the browser:

1- ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

2- ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 21, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}

Comment: Mae sure the API returns the `Obsdervable` of `array` not `object`

Comment: try to parse into JsON like `this.products = res.json()`

Comment: can you explain in more details

Comment: What does your `res` look like? Can you do a `console.log(res)` and show us the output?

Answer (score 2):

Try this it may helps and see the console.log value too

```
 showProducts() {
          this.data.showProducts().subscribe(res => {
                 this.products = res;
                console.log(this.products);
           });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the response comming from the backend.

```
showProducts() {
this.data.showProducts()
  .subscribe(res => this.products = res);
}
```

Just check the "res" here. It might not be an array hence the products.

Answer (score 0):

Your respond from API must be JSON format, if not you should explicitly declare `respondType` in your service. something like:

```
   apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/products'
   showProducts() {
        return this.http.get<Product[]>(this.apiUrl, {observe: 'response', 
   resposeType: 'text'});
   }
```

it seems nothing wrong with your DOM or Component.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way it will help and also optimized and check console log value

```
showProducts(): void {
  this.data.showProducts().subscribe(( this.products: any) => {
    console.log(this.products); 
    });
  }
```